# Client side state saving, any way I could see state data sent to client?

Tags: java, jsf, state-saving

In order to decide a better state saving method for my JSF app from amongst server side & client side saving, I wanting to see the saved state data when the state is saved to client.

I need to have an idea of how much data is transferred back & forth between the requests & if I reduce that to keep the advantages of client side saving(like all time responsiveness & no dead app after view expires)! 
Could I see this saved state in firebug plugin in firefox ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes firefox's firebug plugin can help with that. Just see the view state transferred upon each `request` in the `XHR` section under the `Net` panel.

---

Looks something like this:

```
<partial-response>
    <changes>
         <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">
                <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]]> 
         </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```